# Harddisk disappeared after BSoD

Tags: hard-drive, bsod

Recently my pc bluescreened and when I rebooted it my second harddrive didn't show up in explorer.
I checked disk management and it does show up there but I can't access any files.
How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Is recognized in the BIOS?

Comment: It is recognized.

Comment: If it shows up in Disk Management it should show up in the BIOS as well. Check if there's a drive letter assigned to the drive in DM, else do the needful.

Comment: No drive letter assigned to the primary partition and 927GB of free space. What do you mean with 'the needful'?

Comment: @Finn I think he means try to assign it a drive letter.

Comment: The button to assing a drive letter is grey.

Comment: Does disk management indicate if it has a filesystem and partitions?  In the past I have recieved BSOD when I had a failing hdd.

Comment: It has one primary partition and a huge free space and that's it. It does say healthy so I guess it isn't failing.

Comment: I found out how to create a new volume, however, this only works for the free space. How can I add the primary partition to the free space or how do I create a volume out of every partition on the harddrive?

Comment: @Finn - If this "free space" didn't exist before the BSOD then the partition was lost which means something mechanical happen.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Use the command line tool [diskpart](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766465%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

- Open command prompt.
- Type `diskpart`.
- Type `list disk` to see a list of disks.
- Type `select disk N`  (where `N` is the disk you want).
- Type `detail disk` to see partitions.
- Type `select volume N` (where `N` is the volume you want).
- Type assign letter=X  (where `X` is the drive letter).

Comment: It didn't take long to start at first, but after the bluescreen it doesn't show up at all. In DM it says it's online though.

Comment: @Finn: Updated my answer, try this way.

Comment: When I enter the drive letter it originall had (D) it says: The volume you selected is not valid or does not exist.

Comment: Do I have to create the volume first because it doesn't seem to exist anymore.

Comment: @Finn - If you create the volume the data that did exist on the now non-existant volume will be lost.

Comment: @Ramhound is right. If you see unallocated space in Disk Management when earlier there was none, you've lost one or more partitions. Stop using the drive and get started on data recovery right away! Edit: Never mind, I see you [created a new partition already](http://superuser.com/questions/620541/how-to-create-a-new-volume-with-free-space#comment771055_620541).

Comment: I can still recover the files even though I created a new volume.