# How to create a new volume with free space

Tags: windows

I tried googling it but I couldn't find any answers so I thought I'll ask it here.
I've got a harddrive with a lot of free space and 1 primary partition but every time I click new simple volume and set a size for the volume which is below the size of the free space it says: There is not enough space available on the disk(s) to complete the operation.
Any idea why?

Comment: Are you using a program to do this or are you going to Computer from the Start Menu?

Comment: I didn't use a program I clicked new simple volume in disk management.

Comment: I used a program this time (MiniTool Partition Wizard Home Edition) and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You need to shrink your existing partition first before adding a new partition.

- Open `Disk Management`
- Right-click `(C:)` and select `Shrink Volume`
- Enter the amount you would like to shrink the volume by, in MiB (1024^2).
- Click `Shrink`

After Windows Shrinks the C: volume, you can then go in and add a new volume that is less than or equal to the amount you just shrank the C: volume by, assuming you didn't have any existing free space.